# Use Command Line for Github and push Xcode projects to Github

Tags: xcode, github, upload, push, git-remote

I just started using github and im having a really difficult time understanding how to use it with command line, as well as push my Xcode projects to github. I've googled whole bunch of stuff but it just didn't work on my computer. Could anybody tell me what exactly I need to do here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, simply go to the root folder of your XCode project: there should be a `.git` folder in it if that project is already under version control.

Create an Empty GitHub repo on ther GitHub site under your account.

Then in the root folder of your project, type:

```
git remote add origin https://<yourAccount>@github.com/<yourAccount>/<yourRepo>
git push -u origin master
```